# How to communicate with each other in two android phones through BluetoothGatt

Tags: android, bluetooth-gatt

At the server side, I set:

```
val bluetoothLeAdvertiser: BluetoothLeAdvertiser = mBleAdapter!!.bluetoothLeAdvertiser
    bluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, advertiseData, scanResponseData, callback)
}

private var mGattServer:BluetoothGattServer? = null
private fun initServices() {
    mGattServer = mBleManager?.openGattServer(this, gattServerCallback) as BluetoothGattServer
    val gattService = BluetoothGattService(Constants.BLE_SERVICE_UUID, BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY)
    val characteristicRead = BluetoothGattCharacteristic(Constants.BLE_READ_UUID, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ)
    val descriptor = BluetoothGattDescriptor(Constants.BLE_DESC_UUID, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE)
    characteristicRead.addDescriptor(descriptor)
    gattService.addCharacteristic(characteristicRead)
    val characteristicWrite = BluetoothGattCharacteristic(Constants.BLE_WRITE_UUID, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE or
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ or BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE)
    gattService.addCharacteristic(characteristicWrite)
    mGattServer?.addService(gattService)
}
```

and UUIDS define as:

```
val BLE_SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
val BLE_WRITE_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
val BLE_READ_UUID  = UUID.fromString("00002a03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
val BLE_DESC_UUID  = UUID.fromString("00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
```

and when run the server app, it print onServiceAdded:status=0, which means that the service is added ok.

But when the client app connects to the GattServer and print all characteristics in all services, I find:

```
Connected to GATT server.
SUUID:00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
CUUID:00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Properties:32
SUUID:00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
CUUID:00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Properties:2
CUUID:00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Properties:2
CUUID:00002aa6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Properties:2
```

No UUID same as that i setted in the server side, and no UUID has properties with BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE.

Why? How can i sent data from the client to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scan use following code, can get the right result:

```
List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
            .setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(Constants.SERVICE_UUID))
            .build();
    filters.add(scanFilter);
    ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
            .build();
    /*mScanResults = new HashMap<>();
    mScanCallback = new BtleScanCallback(mScanResults);*/
    mScanCallback = new BtleScanCallback();
    mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
```